# Contar el tiempo que se detecta una sonrisa en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

Tengo un programa que detecta los rostros (en el primer for) y las sonrisas (en el segundo for anidado), lo que estoy tratando es de obtener los segundos que la persona sonrie para poder mostrarlo en pantalla después.

```py
def detectFaces(self):

    ret, self.frame = self.cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    self.faces = self.faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)


    self.lblFaceDetect.setText('Face not detected')
    self.lblFaceDetect.setStyleSheet("color: red;")

    for (x, y, w, h) in self.faces:

        cv2.rectangle(self.frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        roiGray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
        roiColor = self.frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        self.lblFaceDetect.setText('Face detected')
        self.lblFaceDetect.setStyleSheet("color: green;")

        self.smiles = self.smileCascade.detectMultiScale(roiGray, 1.8, 20)

        self.thread2 = threading.Thread(name='threadCount', target=self.countSmiling)

        for (sx, sy, sw, sh) in self.smiles: 
            cv2.rectangle(roiColor, (sx, sy), ((sx + sw), (sy + sh)), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            if not self.thread2.is_alive():
                self.thread2.start()

    self.frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    height, width, channel = self.frame.shape
    step = channel * width

    qImg = QImage(self.frame.data, width, height, step, QImage.Format_RGB888)

    self.lblVideo.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))


def countSmiling(self):
    if len(self.smiles) > 0:
        self.Sec += 1
        print(str(self.Min) + " Mins " + str(self.Sec) + " Sec ")

        cv2.putText(self.frame, "Time: " + str(self.Min) + " Mins " + str(self.Sec) + " Sec ", (0,self.frame.shape[0] -30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5,  (0,0,255), 1)
        cv2.putText(self.frame, "Number of faces detected: " + str(self.faces.shape[0]), (0,self.frame.shape[0] -10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5,  (0,0,255), 1)    

        time.sleep(1)
        if self.Sec == 59:
            self.Sec = 0
            self.Min += 1
            print(str(self.Min) + " Minute")
```

Logro cambiar cosas de estado dependiendo si está sonriendo o no, pero no sé como poder medir ese intervalo de tiempo.

### Actualización

He logrado hacer más o menos lo que quería con threads, ahora los problemas son 2:

1. Cuando se detecta una sonrisa empieza a contar, todo bien, cuando se deja de sonreir deja de contar, todo bien, pero cuando se vuelve a sonreir sigue la cuenta en el segundo que se quedó anteriormente (lo cual lo puedo usar para calcular el total de segundos sonreidos pero no para mostrar los segundos sonreidos en cada momento, pero bueno...).
2. Pero lo que sí es molesto es que los segundos no se cuentan como segundos, a lo que me refiero es que el conteo empieza a darse de manera descontrolada, el `time.sleep(1)` que he puesto lo ignora completamente.

Comment: Cuando detectes la sonrisa, captura qué hora es llamando a `time.time()`, y guardala en una variable. Cuando detectes que dejó de sonreir, captura de nuevo la hora y réstala de la anterior.

Comment: @abulafia sí, pero lo que necesito no es el tiempo total, si no cada segundo que está sonriendo en tiempo real, mientras está sonriendo un marcado va subiendo segundo a segundo durante el tiempo que permanezca sonriendo.

Comment: Bueno, entonces tendrás que tener algún disparador de eventos cada segundo (u otra unidad de tiempo que desees). Guardas en un booleano global que no está sonriendo. En el manejador de ese evento, detectas sonrisa, si la hay, y el booleano dice que no sonreía, tomas nota de la hora y pones el booleano a true. Si la hay, y el booleano era true (es decir, sigue sonriendo), calculas la diferencia entre la hora actual y la de inicio de sonrisa y muestras el resultado como "tiempo sonriendo". Si no hay sonrisa pones el booleano a false y muestras 0 en el "tiempo sonriendo".

Comment: Creo que lo que está ocurriendo es que estás lanzando múltiples hilos de conteo, pues tienes la creación de ese hilo dentro de un bucle. Cada hilo de conteo sí que espera 1 segundo, pero al tener muchos, sus salidas se mezclan y solapan y por eso parece que no esperan.

Comment: Pues de todas las formas que lo prueba, de ninguna manera se soluciona